# When did Bhagavan Shree Ram take birth?

Tags: vishnu, ramayana, rama, treta-yuga

[Wikipedia says](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treta_Yuga#:%7E:text=Vamana%2C%20Parashurama%2C%20and%20Rama%20are,lived%20during%20the%20Treta%20Yuga.) Shree Ram was born in middle half of Treta Yug.

And this page also says Treta Yug lasted 1296000 years.

But [this page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rama) and also the film [Ram setu](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ram_Setu_(film)) says Lord Ram took brith approximately 7000 years ago. But according to the Treta yug it should be far more than 7000 years ago.

Then what is the real truth?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142020/discussion-on-question-by-siddharth-when-did-shree-ram-born).

Comment: @Siddharth rama was never born.  it's only a poet's dream...

Comment: @blue_ego It's not a poet's dream. Several proves exists. And I never asked from you whether he was born or not. So, you meed just to get lost from here. (Never mind)